# Parsing html elelments on form POST in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, pug, body-parser

I'm trying to parse select (dropdown) box element on form post.

Request body contains only 'txt1' element. No sign of 'lstSelect' element.

I know I should use a body-parser but don't know  how and which one?

This is the Jade template:

```
 extends layout
    block content
    .jumbotron
        h1 Calculator
        form(action='/calc',method='post', id="tableForm" )
            p
            select(name="lstSelect", id="lstSelect", size ="5")
            option(value='one') One
            option(value='two') Two
            option(value='three') Three
            p
            input(type='text', name='txt1', id='txt1') 
            p  
            input(type='submit' name='StdDev', value='StdDev')
```

This is the NodeJS file:

```
//"use strict";
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var api = require('./routes/api/index');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multiparty = require('multiparty');
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.post('/calc', function (req, res) {
    var lstSelect = req.body.lstSelect; <- undefined
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
        // fields fields fields
        var x = 1; <- bp never reached
    });
    var b = req.body; <- only txt1 element is here
});
```

EDIT: big flaw. Selected value is in request.body BUT I still need whole list. I need array of Select box values.

Answer (score 0):

The `select` doesn't have any `option` elements, so it's skipped when submitting. The following should fix it;

```
extends layout

block content
    .jumbotron
        h1 Calculator
        form(action='/calc', method='post', id='tableForm')
            p
                select(name='lstSelect', id='lstSelect', size='5')
                    option(value='one') One
                    option(value='two') Two
                    option(value='three') Three
            p
                input(type='text', name='txt1', id='txt1') 
            p  
                input(type='submit' name='StdDev', value='StdDev')
```

Also fixed some indentation so your input elements are inside the paragraphs.

Comment: thanks . that is true. but still does not solve my problem.question updated.

Comment: It's now an indentation problem. `select` needs to be one indent inside `p` and `option`s need to be one indent inside `select` to be valid children elements. Your current indentation means they're siblings, not children. Look at my answer for the correct indentation.